# Where can I browse the Deployments that I made using the AzureRM_Template_Deployment resource of Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template

Recently I have started doing some Azure Data Factory deployments using the AzureRM_Template_Deployment resource in Terraform using Azure DevOps. I need to be able to browse all the deployments I made using this resource. When I open the Deployments folder in the Azure portal I do not see anything there. But I'm sure this deployment exists because if I use the same name for a future template deployment using Terraform, I get the below error:

```
resource with the ID "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/<deploymentName>" already exists
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating a storage account from the sample registry I found from [azurerm_template_deployment Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/template_deployment), after the deployment was successful, If I go to the deployment folder from portal I don’t find any . Its because we didn’t use the template on subscription level rather we used on resource group. We deploy the resources using the ARM template to the resource group that’s being created by terraform.

[image]

So, we can find the template deployment inside the resource group under the deployment blade as shown.

[image]

[image]